# How to add image in-between a parsed list in qt

Tags: qt

I am getting the values in a list from the parser., i need to add a image in-between them., i tried to append them but i am not able to insert a image., is there any possibility to show a image in-between the list,which is coming from parser.

```
         QImageReader imageReader(":/images/detail.png");
          myImage= imageReader.read();

  //   QPixmap myImage = new QPixmap();
  //   myImage = (":/images/detail.png");

    strList << sendername + myImage + "\n" + Receive  + myImage+ "\n" + place;
```

I tried in these QimageReader and also using Qpixmap ways but i could not find any solution in setting up an image in the list!

Comment: You cannot put an image into a string list. Where do you display the list? If you're using HTML, you can add something like "<img src=":/images/detail.png"/>" instead of reading the image with QImageReader.

Comment: Is there any other possibility other than adding to string.. i cannot able to use html here., I am having a listview,that displays items between that i need to add the picture.,

Comment: I want to add the image at the place of "myImage", image should be there instead.,  during runtime

Comment: Which model class are you using with your listview ?

Comment: I cant get you alexisdm., which modal class means. i dont understand

Comment: I had used QStringList strList; in that program... for getting the parsed value

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you use to display the "string" must be able to handle references to images embedded in the string. If you're using a `QListView` or a `QListWidget`, you'd need to implement a custom delegate class that can interpret the image reference and act appropriately.